# backbone: What is the purpose of this.$el.children().detach();?

Tags: backbone.js

I am reading some backbone source code and in all the parent views I see the following line of code:

```
this.$el.children().detach();
```

I can't figure out the purpose for this though. I think it has something to do with resetting the parents content in the case we want to rerender the parent for some reason. Is this the reason or is it something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the jquery documentation:

> The .detach() method is the same as .remove(), except that .detach()
>   keeps all jQuery data associated with the removed elements. This
>   method is useful when removed elements are to be reinserted into the
>   DOM at a later time.

http://api.jquery.com/detach/

Sample code given as illustration:

```
<p>Hello</p>
how are
<p>you?</p>
<button>Attach/detach paragraphs</button>

<script>
$( "p" ).click(function() {
  $( this ).toggleClass( "off" );
});
var p;
$( "button" ).click(function() {
  if ( p ) {
    p.appendTo( "body" );
    p = null;
  } else {
    p = $( "p" ).detach();
  }
});
</script>
```

Comment: I have read that and I understand what detach does. I just don't understand why someone would put it in the render method of all their backbone parent Views.

Comment: `this.$el` returns a jquery object of the views el, while `children` returns the direct descendants. What it does is `detach` the child elements, so they can be re-appended later. If the developer added this code, then this is the desired result. I'm not sure how to explain this otherwise.